# Using lodash to filter data

Tags: javascript, lodash

The goal is to find all objects in "allInvoices" array  that have a corresponding invoiceId in "selectedIds" array.

I am currently using lodash and achieving it as below. I was wondering if there is a more elegant method of performing this task using lodash, chaining or whatever.

```
var selectedIds = [
  { invoiceId: 2, customerId: 34 },
  { invoiceId: 4, customerId: 49}
  ];

var allInvoices = [
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Ron',
    date: '2015-14-12'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Harry'
  },
  {
    id:4,
    name: 'snowpiercer'
  },
  {
    id:5,
    name: 'birdman'
  },
  {
    id:6,
    name: 'superman'
  }
  ];

  var  result = [];

  _.forEach(selectedIds, function(myId) {

    var eachInvoice = _.find(allInvoices,{id: myId.invoiceId});
    result.push(eachInvoice);

  });

  console.log(result);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/btB3aEwPDotao9kMtgFm?p=info

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach:

```
_(allInvoices)
    .groupBy('id')
    .at(_.pluck(selectedIds, 'invoiceId'))
    .flatten()
    .value()
```

- [groupBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy) creates an object where the ids are the keys
- [at()](https://lodash.com/docs#at) creates an array, picking values *at* specific keys
- [flatten()](https://lodash.com/docs#flatten) removes array nesting

Answer (score 0):

It's not much tidier; but this saves any nested looping (caused by `_.find`):

```
var pluckedIds = _.pluck( selectedIds, "invoiceId" ); // [2,4]

var result = _.filter( allInvoices, function ( invoice ) {
  return pluckedIds.indexOf( invoice.id ) !== -1;
});
```